# Is it possible to change the value of the Document (root-node) Attribute at runtime in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to change the value of the Document (root-node) Attribute at runtime in XSL?

like:

```
<Document xmlns="http:\\someURL.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
```

to:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
```

Comment: xmlns is not an attribute, it's a namespace. But you can declare the namespace of an element with <xsl:element namespace=...

Comment: Of course `xmlns` is an attribute. For parsers that are not name space aware it is a normal attribute, for name space aware parser it is a reserved attribute (and treated specially).

Answer (score 1):

xmlns is not an attribute, it the document namespace.

( sometimes things like namespace declarations, or parts of processing instructions that 
  look syntactically similar to attributes, having a key=value format are called 
  pseudo-attributes. )

But you can copy an element and declare it in a different namespace with something like:

```
    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"  namespace="urn:iso:std:iso" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>   
   </xsl:template>
```